# Uniform convergence for the sequence $\psi_n(x)=n^{-1}e^{-n^2/(n^2-x^2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory, uniform-convergence

How can I prove that the sequence of functions:

\begin{equation}
\psi_n(x)=\begin{cases} n^{-1}e^{-n^2/(n^2-x^2)}, & |x|\leq n \\ 0, & |x|\geq n \end{cases}
\end{equation}

convergences uniformly to zero and that the same happens for all the sequences which are defined as the $\psi_n^{(k)}(x), k\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, derivatives of $\psi_n(x)$? And one last thing, why the sequence $\psi_n(x)$ does not converge to the zero element of the space $\mathcal{D}$?

I am having difficulties with uniform convergence, therefore your assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Rewritten, $\psi_n(x)=\phi(x/n)/n$, where $\phi$ is the standard bump function in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Moya I don't yet have familiarity with bump functions :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphically, what this function looks like is essentially a bump. On the set $|x|\leq n$, it looks like a plateau that quickly drops off to 0 as $|x|\to n$. So naturally, as $n\to \infty$, the function is essentially going to approach a constant function, and since the height of the plateau is proportional to $1/n$, this has to approach the $0$ function (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) for a picture).

Fix $\epsilon>0$. We want to find an $N$ such that $||\psi_n||_u<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$, where $||\cdot ||_u$ is the supremum norm on continuous functions. It's not too hard to see that $||\psi_n||_u=\frac{1}{n e}$, so obviously the result holds. The case for the derivatives is similar.

To see that $\psi_n\not\to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, note that there is no compact set $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $\text{supp} \psi_n\subset K$ for all $n$ ( $\text{supp}\psi_n=[-n,n]$, so $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[-n,n]=\mathbb{R}\subset K$, which is impossible, so $K$ cannot exist) so by definition there is no convergence.

Comment: But why $\| \psi_n\|_u=1/ne$? I am having a problem while trying to show that.

Comment: Compute the first derivative of $\psi_n(x)$. The derivative vanishes only when $x=0$. Thus $x=0$ is the only max/min (since the derivative is positive on $(-\epsilon, 0)$ and negative on $(0,\epsilon)$ for small epsilon, this must be a max). Thus this is a global maximum of this function. See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B%281%2Fn%29e%5E%281%2F%28%28x%2Fn%29%5E2-1%29%29%2Cx%5D

Comment: For the derivatives, play around on wolfram alpha. You'll find by induction that the maximum of each derivative must be proportional to $n$, so that $||\psi_n^(k)||=C_n/n$. If you can show $C_n$ is always proportional to $e^{-a}$ for some $a>0$, so that $C_n\leq 1 $ for all $n$ and the result holds.